# How convert dataset value in string in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataSet ContactorName = Employee.GetContractorName(CompanyID, LocationId, ContractorCode);
string ConName= ContactorName.Tables[0].ToString();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: want to convert dataset value in string variable

Comment: convert to what?? There is no enough info provided in the question.

Comment: Read this post about how to ask questions. 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You have to describe what is your question and what you have done, what is the error, etc

Comment: please give me answer

Comment: No question description....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
  DataSet ContactorName = Employee.GetContractorName(CompanyID, LocationId, ContractorCode);
   string ConName = ContactorName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContractorName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the row and the column to get content from [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) ;)

```
DataSet ContactorName = Employee.GetContractorName(CompanyID, LocationId, ContractorCode);
string ConName = ContactorName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

*PS: For your next questions, add some text for explain your problem.*